# mysql count with both varchar and int

Tags: mysql

What is a good way to count and group by a column that may have an INT or varchar?

I'm trying to find duplicates in a table (not mine) where someone "wisely" added department numbers with and without a leading zero.

example data within the field bank_cnt_fk may contain:

```
   bank_cnt_fk
   03000001080
   3000001080
```

These are essentially both the same but there are different systems feeding two different types of data into this database.  I need to find the duplicates so I can clean this mess up.

This following query doesn't seem to work because nothing is coming up greater than 1.

```
SELECT id, bank_cnt_fk, count(cast(bank_cnt_fk as unsigned))
FROM org_desc_data group by bank_cnt_fk
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT id,cast(bank_cnt_fk as unsigned), count(*) 
FROM org_desc_data group by cast(bank_cnt_fk as unsigned)`

Comment: Thanks this works for me, not sure why I didn't think of it before... ><

Comment: I have written it as answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52099763/2469308 - you may accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
SELECT id,
      CAST(bank_cnt_fk AS UNSIGNED), 
      COUNT(*) 
FROM org_desc_data 
GROUP BY CAST(bank_cnt_fk AS UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment given by @Madhur is probably the best answer to your question.  There is another option, namely stripping off all leading zeroes:

```
SELECT
    TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM bank_cnt_fk) bank_cnt_fk,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM org_desc_data
GROUP BY
    TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM bank_cnt_fk);
```